# when clicked on an href the new URL doesn't reload the page in Svelte

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm currently trying to redirect the user to a new page when they clicked on a href link.
The problem is that the url does change per se, but only when I manually hit "reload", the page actually refreshes and shows the new data.

How I build the href-link:

```js
resultString += "<a href='/edition/id=" + this.note['name'][i]['hkg:persKey'] + "'>";
resultString += this.note['name'][i]['#text'];
resultString += "</a>";
```

The resultString then gets pushed to an array and is correctly read out in another component.

The problem is, that when redirected, the id in the url visibly changes and is updated in the url but the page doesn't reload.

for example:
on page with `'id=xy'` the URL is: `'/edition/id=xy'` and on this page, the href `'/edition/id=z'` is displayed.
When clicking on this href, the url changes visibly to `'/edition/id=z'` but the page doesn't reload.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Any updates on this one? Using `rel="external"` feels like cheating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a feature of Sveltekit. You could try adding `rel=external` to your links

```
<a rel="external" href="path">Path</a>
```

Source: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-reload

Comment: Silly feature, break standard linking html :-/

Answer (score 13):

Once I encountered the same behavior. I don't remember what it was, but I cured it with **target="_self"**

Comment: I was navigating to a local element using `<a href="#my-element">Click</a>` and I noticed it refreshed the whole page every time. Apparently this [`target="_self"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68326006/target-blank-opens-in-new-tabs-in-firefox-but-not-chrome-svelte) is a thing you're supposed to do when linking internally. I dunno how I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem today, and after a while looking around I found this in SvelteKit FAQs:

It's likely you're destructuring values from data without making them reactive. Reactive destructuring looks like this:

$: ({ user } = data)

You can also save a line of code by calling data.user directly in markup.

Comment: Found this question while trying to reload data in my page when the params change, so I don't want the page to really reload. So you can use a reactive statement alongside the params store (from `import { page } from "$app/stores";`) : `$: loadData($page.params.id)`

Answer (score 1):

According to Svelte's current documentation this should work

```
<a data-sveltekit-reload href="/path">Path</a>
```

The link provided by Alexvdvalk helped me out
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-reload