# target="_blank" opens in new tabs in firefox but not chrome (Svelte)

Tags: html, svelte

I have a small single page application with a few internal links and a few external links. I want all of the external links to automatically open in a new tab and so I have set the html as follows:

```
    <base target="_blank" />
```

This works great in chrome. When I click links on my navbar, my site navigates within the same tab, and when I click on an external link it dutifully opens in a new tab.

However, when I visit my website with firefox (several versions tested), every single link, even the internal ones on my navbar, opens in a new tab.

How can I correct this so that only external links open in new tabs on all browsers?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried being explicit on the navbar links? Like using `target="_self"` on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static solution would be to be explicit on internal links, that is, adding `target="_self"` to those.

If you don't want that, Javascript might also be able to help, depending on your setup.

Assuming your internal links are all relative or at least server-absolute links, and assuming your page is static (like links are not added to the page after `DOMContentLoaded`), the following Javascript snippet would solve the task:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  for (const externalLink of document.querySelectorAll('a[href^=http]'))
    externalLink.target = '_blank';
})
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="/">Some internal link</a>
```

As another dude has pointed out, of course this only works if your links are accessible from the document (not if they reside inside a shadowDOM).

Comment: Not necessarily, if svelte is compiled as custom html components with shadow dom

Comment: Downvote for suggesting to add global JavaScript dom manipulation when the tool of choise is component-based framework

Answer (score 0):

As per @connexo's comment, I solved the issue by explicitly stating

```
target="_self"
```

in the navbar links.

Comment: I've added this to my answer, along with a Javascript alternative.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the target specifically for external links, if you want to override browser default functionality. Make a link component that does this.